# font-size 10px cant apply, always 12px

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, font-size

Simple code, but in chrome font-size is always 12px, in IE it's 10px.
For px larger than 12, it's ok to change. But for px under 12, it cant be changed....how to fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" >
    body{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    div{
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 60em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        wrapper
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a minimum font-size set in Chrome?

Comment: This is your only code you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In chrome://settings/fonts, there is a setting for "minimum font size". You probably have that set to 12px.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the size of text in chrome.

- Click  Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- In the "Web Content" section, use the "Font size" drop-down menu to make adjustments.

[see here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96810)

Comment: You mean my clients have to adjust their settings so they can have the right size I want them to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try change size like this:

```
body {
        font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, you would probably have some javascript changing it on the fly (do you have some javascript plugins or code loaded with your project?

Or maybe css from other plugins/modules/code etc.

Or maybe you have really set some minimum font size in chrome settings. Try to check taht also.